# ¿Cómo definir y obtener el nombre de la aplicación en Grails 3?

Tags: grails

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Grails 3 y necesitaría saber, por una parte, cómo definir el nombre de la aplicación y por otra, cómo obtener el nombre de la aplicación dentro de un servicio. He estado mirando y he visto que se debe de definir en el build.gradle, pero no he encontrado cómo. He probado con las siguientes opciones:

```
app.name="mediacion"
```

o bien:

```
appName="mediacion"
```

Pero ninguna de las dos funciona.
También necesito obtener el nombre de la aplicación en un servicio. Lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

```
GrailsApplication grailsApplication
def nombreApp = grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'
```

La variable nombreApp siempre vale null. Seguramente porque no defino bien el nombre de la aplicación en build.gradle o porque el código para obtener el nombre también está mal ¿Alguna idea de cómo debo definir y obtener el nombre de la aplicación?

Answer (score 1):

Saludos, la siguiente sentencia te ayudara en tu objetivo:

```
GrailsApplication grailsApplication

def nombreApp = grailsApplication.config.appName
```